# Django - Best practice to join two models

Tags: python, django, models

I'm developing a project that allows users to make a test based in some random questions.
My models.py has this two classes:

```
class Question(models.Model):
    content = models.CharField()
    ...

class Answer(models.Model):
    content = models.CharField()
    isCorrect = models.BooleanField()
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question)
```

And in my views.py I get 20 random questions using this query:

```
questions = Question.objects.order_by('?')[:20]
```

With this approach I have only the questions but I want also the answers related to every question, I found some solutions but I'd like to know what could be the best practice to get Question and related Answers? Can I add them to Question constructor?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do as @karthikr said, but it will make an extra database call for each question.

I would do it maybe this way:

```
questions = Question.objects.order_by('?')[:20]
answers = Answer.objects.filter(question__in=questions)

#some databases will not suppoert this, so use:
#answers = Answer.objects.filter(question_id__in=[q.id for q in questions])

for question in question:
    answers_for_question = filter(lambda answer:answer.question_id = question_id, answers)
```

Which is only 2 db calls instead of 21

(For a really large sets of questions, make use of [itertools](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html) to get the answers. for even better performance)

Comment: You could just do `questions.values_list('id', flat=True)`

Comment: But than he won't have the Question objects